# dup2( ) causing child process to terminate early

Tags: c++, unix, fork, pipe, dup2

So I'm writing a program that involves the creation of 2 sets of pipes so that a parent process can write to a child process & the child process can right back...

I have the following code for my child process:

```
if(pid==0){  //child process
        cout << "executing child" << endl;
        close(fd1[WRITE_END]);
        close(fd2[READ_END]);
        if(dup2(fd1[READ_END],STDIN_FILENO) < 0 || dup2(fd2[WRITE_END],STDOUT_FILENO) < 0){
            cerr << "dup2 failed" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        cout << "test output" << endl;
        close(fd2[WRITE_END]);
        close(fd1[READ_END]);
        read(fd1[READ_END],buf,BUFFER_SIZE);
        cout << "Child process read " << buf << endl;
        execl("/bin/sort", "sort", "-nr", NULL);


    } else {  //... parent process
```

When I run my program, all I get as output from the child process is `executing child` but no `test output`.
However, when I remove the if-statement handling the dup2 calls, my output does include `test output`.

Any ideas as to why dup2 causes my child process to not finish terminating?

(and by the way, originally, my two dup2's were done in separate if statements... when I put the test output below the `dup2(fd1[READ_END],STDIN_FILENO) < 0` test, it outputs, but not when I put it below the other dup2 conditional test, so I'm convinced that that's where my issue is)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to dup2(fd2[WRITE_END],STDOUT_FILENO) connects STDOUT (which is used by C++ cout stream) to your fd2 pipe. So 'test output' gets written to the pipe.